# Error The target-entity App\Entity\Productos cannot be found in 'App\Entity\Categoria#productos'

Tags: php, symfony4

Intento unir las 2 tablas pero cuando intento hacer `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` me sale ese error y no se que pueda ser. para poder actualizar la DB.
mi entidad Categoria, en donde estoy haciendo la unión de uno a muchos.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use App\Repository\CategoriaRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoriaRepository::class)
 */
class Categoria
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Productos", mappedBy="categoria")
     */
    private $productos;

    /**
     * Categoria constructor.
     * @param $nombre
     * @param $productos
     */
    public function __construct($nombre=null)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->productos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function AgregarProduto(Producto $producto){
        $this->productos[] = $producto;
    }
}
```

y la entidad Producto, la cual estoy haciendo de muchos a uno, y se esta usando un constructor para poder agregar fácilmente y se inicializa en nulo, teniendo dentro un array para poder agregar el producto que se quiere guardar en la base de datos.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductoRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductoRepository::class)
 */
class Producto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $codigo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Categoria", inversedBy="productos")
     */
    private $categoria;

    /**
     * Producto constructor.
     * @param $nombre
     * @param $codigo
     */
    public function __construct($nombre=null, $codigo=null)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getCodigo() { 
        return $this->codigo; 
    } 

    public function setCodigo($codigo) {  
        $this->codigo = $codigo; 
    } 
}
```

Usando Symfony 4, y siguiendo guías ninguna da error, y no entiendo el porque este error o que le falta  al código para que pueda funcionar bien, y pueda guardar los productos que quiero en la DB.

Comment: Que pasa si le pones solo `targetEntity="Productos"`? (ya que ambos están en el mismo namespace)... o intentar poniendo un \ al inicio...  `targetEntity="\App\Entity\Categoria"`. Porque sin el \ al inicio sería una ruta relativa al namespace actual.

Comment: de las 2 maneras sigue el mismo error